# Joins in query not pulling through correctly

Tags: sql

Good evening. Could someone please help me with the following. I am trying to join two tables.The first id wbr_global.gl_ap_details. This stores historic GL information. The second table sandbox.utr_fixed_mapping is where account mapping is stored. For example, ana ccount number 60820 is mapped as Employee relation. The first table needs the mapping from the second table linked on the account number. The output I am getting is not right and way to bug. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Output]

```
select sandbox.utr_fixed_mapping_na.new_mapping_1,sum(wbr_global.gl_ap_details.amount)
from wbr_global.gl_ap_details 
LEFT JOIN sandbox.utr_fixed_mapping_na ON wbr_global.gl_ap_details.account_number = sandbox.utr_fixed_mapping_na.account_number   
Where gl_ap_details.cost_center = '1172'
and gl_ap_details.period_name = 'JUL-21'
and gl_ap_details.ledger_name = 'Amazon.com, Inc.'
Group by 1;
```

[image: Exceprt from Mapping]

[image: Excerpt from GL]

I tried adding the cast function but after 5000 seconds of the query running I canceled it.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. The query doesn't look difficult, but it's not 100% clear what you need [to me].

Comment: That is the full output of the query. Right now in the first table there 4 buckets with the associated accounts that role into it. For example there may be 20 different account # that fall into employee benefits such as payroll, medical, or workers comp. The GL table just has account numbers so I am trying to buckect them based on the logic in the mapping table.I added an excerpt from the mapping table in the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Looks to me like the sandbox acct_number is stored as a numeric whereas account_number in the global_gl_AP_Details is text.  note the right and left alignment of the values.  The implicit type conversion may be causing the issue leading to leading zero truncation.  So... What are the datatypes of the Account_number in both tables and what should the ending datatype be?  since you'll not be doing math on it; i'd assume a varchar(x) is appropriate.  so the account_number in the sandbox as numeric is likely a bad choice for data type.

Comment: Lastly in your results that are wrong, include the account number from both tables as it may help isolate the problem  focus in one one account that you know to be wrong and what the correct value should be; and the data that makes up that correct value.  but my guess is still an implicit type conversion causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you, the account number in the sandbox.utr_fixed_mapping_na account ID is an integer and wbr_global.gl_ap_details account id is a varchar.Both should be varchar. The correct values are around 30MM-50mm per category